# WPF Caliburn.Micro ComboBox IsEditable Text Changed Event not triggering until after Action Event

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, action, caliburn.micro

I've got a test WPF application using Caliburn.Micro. I'm trying to build with a ComboBox that can be typed in. The DataGrid information associated will update/filter as the text is entered.

The issue I'm running into though is that when my ExecuteSearch event gets triggered. It passes the information in before the text was edited. I'm wondering how I can get text information passed to the function after a key is pressed.

Any help would be appreciated. Relevant code below:

View:

```
<TextBlock Text="Search: " />
<ComboBox x:Name="SearchOptions"
          IsEditable="True"
          DisplayMemberPath="Search"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyDown] = [Action ExecuteSearch($source)]"
          MinWidth="200">
</ComboBox>
```

ViewModel:

```
public void ExecuteSearch(object searchText)
    {
        ComboBox searchbox = (ComboBox)searchInfo;
        if (searchbox.Text != null && searchbox.Text != "")
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM SearchItems WHERE PartNumber LIKE " + searchbox.Text +"";
            SearchItems = SqliteConnector.LoadData<SearchItemsModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());
        }
        else
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM SearchItems";
            SearchItems = SqliteConnector.LoadData<SearchItemsModel>(sql, new Dictionary<string, object>());
        }
    }
```

When Event is triggered `searchbox.Text == ""` even though a "0" was entered.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use KeyUp event.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SearchOptions"
          IsEditable="True" 
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event KeyUp] = [Action ExecuteSearch($source)]"
          MinWidth="200">
        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: That makes complete sense. Not sure what I was thinking. I also found another way of having it update as well. But I think this answer is much more simple and to the point.